# Haskell - pattern matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I am trying to iterate through a list of lists and compare lists with each other in the list.

Basically, I have a list of paths and an empty accumulator list, I pick one path (x) and compare it to one of  the others (y) to see whether they are intersected, and if they do, I pop x into the accumulator, and compare y to the rest and so on

```
connected :: [((Integer, Integer), (Integer, Integer))] -> Bool
connected xs = isConnected (getPaths xs) []
    where isConnected [] acc = True
          isConnected [x] acc = True
          isConnected (x:y:zs) acc | (compareList x y == True) = isConnected (zs) (x:acc)  
                                   | otherwise                 = False
```

```
connected :: [((Integer, Integer), (Integer, Integer))] -> Bool
connected xs = isConnected (getPaths xs) []
    where isConnected [] acc = True
          isConnected [x] acc = True
          isConnected (x:y:zs) acc | (compareList x y == True) = isConnected (y:zs) (x:acc)  
                                   | otherwise                 = False
```

I tried both of them and could not pass the test.
I am wondering what's the difference between `(zs)` and `(y:zs)`

Comment: If your original argument is `p`, then `zs == tail (tail p)` and `(y:zs) == tail p`.  Which (if either) you want to use depends on what, exactly, `p = getPaths xs` actually is.

Comment: @chepner Then should I add another base case when there's only two elements left in the list

Comment: `acc` is used in a way which is most likely wrong: `isConnected` does not use `acc` at all except for computing the new value of `acc`. As such, it is a pointless argument since it won't affect the final result. If the aim is to take `[p1,p2,p3,..]` and test `compareList x1 x2 && compareList x2 x3 && ...` then I don't think `acc` is needed at all (but note you need to recurse with `y:zs` for this). If instead you want to check `compareList x1 x2 && compareList x3 x4 && ...` then yuo need to recurse with only `zs` (`acc` is again not needed).

Comment: @chi I pop x into acc using `(x:acc)`, and `y:zs` would keep reducing during the recursive process until it is empty which is `True`, and if it stops in the middle, it would be `False`. I meant to write this using `(x:acc)`, but now I don't know how to use `acc` within the function